# Python - Issue with double quotes while writing to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, double-quotes

I am trying to convert an xml to JSON (condensed version of the code is provided below).

The issue I am facing is with a tag, which can have multiple values (example below). I cannot directly make it as dict, since the key (NAME) can have multiple values. The output generated by the code Vs the expected output is given below.

**python script:**

```
import json

mylist = ['"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstp01"', '"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"']
tmpdict = {}
tmpdict['Events'] = mylist

with open('test.json','w') as fp:
    json.dump(tmpdict,fp,indent=4, sort_keys=False)
```

**Output Generated:**

```
{
    "Events": [
        "\"Event\" : \"BATCHS01-wbstp01\"",
        "\"Event\" : \"BATCHS01-wbstrt01\""
    ]
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{
    "Events": [
        {"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstp01"},
        {"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `mylist` is an array of strings rather than an array of map objects.
You need to remove the outer quote to make it:

```
mylist = [{"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstp01"}, {"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"}]
```

I don't see why you cannot produce this structure from XML. It's rather simple regardless of whether 'key (NAME) can have multiple values'.

Comment: what kind of a data structure are you suggesting for `mylist` ? Its nether a `list` nor a `dict`. Invalid syntax.

Comment: @Chamath a list of maps or tuples. Just fixed the syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can salvage your data by first converting it to valid JSON piecewise and then dumping the JSON into a string or a file:

```
tmpdict = {"Events" : [json.loads('{' + item + '}') for item in mylist]}
json.dumps(tmpdict)
'{"Events": [{"Event": "BATCHS01-wbstp01"}, {"Event": "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"}]}'
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen and DyZ. Your solution worked for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

#### Code:

You can first convert the XML pieces to dict's like:

```
tmpdict['Events'] = [json.loads('{%s}' % x) for x in mylist]
```

#### Test Code:

```
import json

mylist = ['"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstp01"', '"Event" : "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"']
tmpdict = {}
tmpdict['Events'] = [json.loads('{%s}' % x) for x in mylist]

with open('test.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(tmpdict, fp, indent=4, sort_keys=False)
```

#### Results:

```
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "Event": "BATCHS01-wbstp01"
        }, 
        {
            "Event": "BATCHS01-wbstrt01"
        }
    ]
}
```